# Calulate the numbers of an Array inside and Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

How can I calculate the average of numbers in an array that is in an array?

See the image how I get the data in;

[image]

```
const reviews = [
0: ["5", "1"]
1: ["4"]
2:  ["1", "4", "1"]
3: ["1", "4"]
4:  ["5", "4"]
5: []
etc etc
]
```

I would like to know the average of each array so:

```
0: 3
1: 4
2: 2 
etc etc
```

I work in React. I get the data from a selector in React-Redux. I use this for calculating the average review for each user.

code:

```
  const reviews = users
    ? users.map((review) => {
        return review
          ? review.reviews.map((reviewen) => {
              return <p>{reviewen.review}</p>;
            })
          : "loading ";
      })
    : "Loading";

  console.log(reviews);
```

Comment: please post your relevant react code

Comment: please add the array in text form along with the wanted result.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Tried that, But I could not get it to work (maybe i'm not experienced enough?)

Comment: here: https://repl.it/@TheKetan2/FrightenedBoldRoot#index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
const reviews = [
["5", "1"],
["4"],
["1", "4", "1"],
["1", "4"],
["5", "4"]
];
const avgReviews = reviews.map(x => (x.reduce((a,b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b), 0) / x.length));
console.log(avgReviews);
```

Or you could create a new array that combines the average with the aray from which it was calculated.

```js
const reviews = [
["5", "1"],
["4"],
["1", "4", "1"],
["1", "4"],
["5", "4"]
];
const reviews_and_average = reviews.map(x => [x,(x.reduce((a,b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b), 0) / x.length)]);
console.log(reviews_and_average);
```

Comment: Daaammmnnnnn!! You are awesome man! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @AliLotfi you are welcome.